# Set an overlay on top of the iframe and want to get the coordinates when the mouse is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to embed an external page in an iframe on a web page and set an overlay on top of it to get the coordinates of a mouse click.

So far, the coordinate acquisition has worked, but I cannot operate within the iframe because of the overlay.
Is there any way to operate within the iframe and get the coordinates on the overlay at the same time?
The external page is like a simple open-source game, but I would like to avoid modifying that one as much as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="image-container">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="image">
            <iframe src="open-souce_game. html"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

iframe {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    border: none;
}
```

```
// Event listener to get the coordinates of the click
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
    const clickX = event.clientX; // mouse X coordinate
    const clickY = event.clientY; // Y coordinate of mouse
    console.log(`X coordinate of mouse on click: ${clickX}, Y coordinate of mouse on click: ${clickY}`);
});

// Event listener to get the coordinates on click release
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
    const releaseX = event.clientX; // X coordinate of mouse
    const releaseY = event.clientY; // Y coordinate of mouse
    console.log(`X coordinate of mouse on click release: ${releaseX}, Y coordinate of mouse on click release: ${releaseY}`);
});
```